# How to write a WHERE clause that uses the MIN() value of a column in the same the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to write a query with the following logic:

Get all rows that have `state` = "active", that have `retries` < `max_retries`, and (from those qualifying rows) only return the rows with the least `retries`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE state = 'active' 
AND   retries < max_retries 
AND   retries = (SELECT MIN(retries) FROM users);
```

my table:

```
+-----------------------------------------+  
| id   uid   retries  max_retries  state  |  
+-----------------------------------------+  
| 1   Jack     3          5        active |  
| 2   Jill     1          3        active |  
| 3   John     3          3        active |  
| 4   James    0          5        no     |  
| 5   Jim      2          7        no     |  
+-----------------------------------------+
```

In this case, my query should return the row containing `Jill` because Jill has: state = active, retries < max_retries and the smallest number of retries.

However, my attempts always get some incorrect results.
I looked at self join and union etc, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

[EDIT]: 
I think I figured it out now, but could someone please confirm it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE state = 'active'
AND  retries =(SELECT MIN(retries) FROM users WHERE retries < max_retries )
```

Comment: What's the schema like for users and what are the sample content and what output are you expecting?

Comment: the schema is: id , uid , retries , max_retries , state . for example: 1 , Jack , 3 , 5 , active . i would like to have the following output: Array ( uid =>"Jack", retries => 3, max_retries => 5, state => active ). But like i said: i want to filter in the same SQL query all users that don't meet the conditions as: retries < max_retries, state = active . and . get the one(s) with the least number of retries.

Comment: Edit your question so we can easily see the initial table with some records and the desired output

Comment: Why does your query contain `FROM users` twice?

Comment: Only you can confirm if that revised query is providing the results you want/expect. It looks fine in syntax terms.

Comment: @Mawg the 2nd from is in a subquery

Comment: i think i solved it now. sorry for not writing my original post clearer (in terms of format). im still trying to figure out how to format the table :(

Comment: Select table and press CTRL + K. Also, if you got your answer, please post it as answer ;)

Comment: thank you very much @ wast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `state` and `max_enteies` conditions to the main query and the subquery, I am now achieving the expected results.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE
    state = 'active'
    AND retries < max_retries
    AND retries = (
        SELECT 
            MIN(retries)
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            state = 'active'
            AND retries < max_retries
    )
```

Comment: Don't you miss an `and state='active'` in your subquery?